# Prove that minimum of $ f $ on $ |z| = 1 $ is no greater than $ |a_0| + \cdots + |a_m| $

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ D $ be the open unit disk. Suppose $ f \in H(D) \cap C(\bar{D}) $ and write $ f(z) = \sum a_n z^n $ for $ |z| < 1 $. If $ f $ has exactly $ m $ zeros in $ D $, prove that 
$$ \min_{|z|=1} |f(z) | \leq |a_0| + \cdots + |a_m|. $$
My original idea was to prove by contradiction: suppose $$ |f(z)| > |a_0| + \cdots + |a_m| \geq |a_0 + a_1z + \cdots + a_mz^m|. $$
Then if we can use Rouché's theorem, this implies that $ f $ has the same number of zeros as $ f -g $, which is $ m + 1 $, a contradiction. However I don't think I can apply Rouché's theorem since $ f $ is not known to be holomorphic on $ \bar{D} $. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply the same argument to the  $|z|=1-\epsilon$. $\max |f(z)| >|a_0|+|a_1|+...+|a_m|$ implies $|f(z)| >|a_0+a_1z+...+a_mz^{m}|$ for $|z|=1-\epsilon$ of $\epsilon $ is small enough. Als0, number of zeros of a polynomial on the open disk equals the number of zeros on $|z|<1-\epsilon$ for $\epsilon $ is small enough.